# Cannot convert json object received from server to required type so can dissect the data

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular16

I apologize in advance if i am asking too stupid questions but i am really new to angular and i do not understand how to handle a JSON object coming from the server and convert that object into a custom datatype so i can use that data to render on html using ngFor.

I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work. Any help will be very much appreciated.

P.S. please excuse me for the extremely simple html page, application is coming up from scratch and i am working on functionalities and backend server connections before working on the designs.

Below is the Code and screenshots attached.

```
Employee.Component.html

<p>Inside Employee Component.</p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-center" (click)="getAllEmployees1()">getAllEmployees</button>

<div>
    <h2>Employee List</h2>
     {{ employees }}
  </div>
```

```
employee.component.ts file

employees: any;

 constructor(private service: EmployeeServiceService){
  }
  ngOnInit(){

  }

  public getAllEmployees1(){
    this.service.getAllEmployees().subscribe((data)=>{

      this.employees = data;
      console.log("Response: "+ this.employees);
    },
    (error) =>{
      console.error('Error fetching employees: ', error);
    }
    );
  }
```

```
EmployeeService file:

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeServiceService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllEmployees(){
    console.log("Inside get ALL Employees Method.");
    return this.http.get("https://localhost:9090/employee/getAllEmployees",{responseType:'text' as 'json'});
  }
```

```
Employee class type:

export class AddEmployee{
    firstName: any;
    lastName: any;
    address:any;
    project:any
    ssn:any;
    joinDate:any;
    status:any

        constructor(
            firstName: string,
            lastName: string,
            address:string,
            project:string,
            ssn:number,
            joinDate:Date,
            status:number
        ){}
    }
```

I wanted to convert the JSON data coming from the server to AddEmployee type and then run a ngFor loop in the html so i can put everything in the tabular format.

But angular keeps on complaining that the data i am getting is in Object Format and ngFor can only be used on observables and iterators. Below is the image attached of how the object gets pulled from server and when i click on getAllEmployees button, it just renders the object itself. I am not able to print the data if i dont call {{ employees }} directly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoSW0.png)

Error Page: [image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you need to initialize the `employees` variable to an empty array, since it always runs on first load, only after the button is clicked, you are getting the array set.

```
employees: any = [];
```

Here is a mock stackblitz which works fine. Few points to note are:

1. If the service is provided in root, then you need to inject the dependencies

like so.

```
private http = Inject(HttpClient);
```

service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  private http = Inject(HttpClient);
  constructor() {}

  getAllEmployees() {
    console.log('Inside get ALL Employees Method.');
    return of([
      {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        address: 'test',
        project: 'test',
        ssn: 'test',
        joinDate: 'test',
        status: 'test',
      },
      {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        address: 'test',
        project: 'test',
        ssn: 'test',
        joinDate: 'test',
        status: 'test',
      },
      {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        address: 'test',
        project: 'test',
        ssn: 'test',
        joinDate: 'test',
        status: 'test',
      },
      {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        address: 'test',
        project: 'test',
        ssn: 'test',
        joinDate: 'test',
        status: 'test',
      },
    ]); //this.http.get("https://localhost:9090/employee/getAllEmployees",{responseType:'text' as 'json'});
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { AddEmployee } from './add-employee';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HttpClientModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <p>Inside Employee Component.</p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-center" (click)="getAllEmployees1()">getAllEmployees</button>

<div>
    <h2>Employee List</h2>
     {{ employees  | json}}
     
     <table border="1">

  <thead>
    <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
      {{column}}
    </th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of employees; index as i">
      <td *ngFor="let column of columns; index as j">
        {{row[column]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  columns = [
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'address',
    'project',
    'ssn',
    'joinDate',
    'status',
  ];
  employees: Array<AddEmployee> = [];

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  public getAllEmployees1() {
    this.testService.getAllEmployees().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.employees = data;
        console.log('Response: ' + this.employees);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching employees: ', error);
      },
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xtxchz)

Comment: thank you so much for the help. it worked. But i have issues trying the same thing with getting results posted for 1 single object. I guess it is only an issue of html, but i would really appreciate it if you can help with single data object rendering in the html table as well please.

Comment: @devenparekh Could you modify the stackblitz provided and share it back, I will look into it!

Comment: I have the pasted the code change to the one you helped me with here:              https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u8gfq9?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I am getting this error:                                   employee.component.ts:47 ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{"employeeId":1,"firstName":"dan2","lastName":"dan2","address":"st st st st","project":"active","joinDate":"2023-12-04","status":"H1B","ssn":123456788}' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG02200
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3057:31)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:3852:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:3883:9)
)

Comment: @devenparekh The provided [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gqxd1x?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ftest.service.ts) works fine, please do not use ngFor for types that are not arrays( [] ) if its a object, just directly give the reference like so

`<table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
        {{column}}
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns; index as j">
          {{empById[column]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>`

Comment: it is still not working in mine. Yes, stackblitz is showing a working code, but in my browser it is not working. It is still giving me errors. It fetched the response from backend but it is unable to render it in my browser. I tried your above piece of code but it giving me this error in the console and not printing the data in table         : core.mjs:10194 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'employeeId')
    at EmployeeComponent_td_26_Template (employee.component.html:60:11)

Comment: Please have a look above. I have added a new image that shows the error. It is giving the error because of the  <td *ngFor="let column of columns; index as j">           {{empById[column]}}         </td> Code.

Comment: @devenparekh Just do a console.log and analyze the reason, if its a object you can access it directly with <parent>.propertName if its an array you will need an ngFor, all the best, sorry Im not able to help much here!

Comment: @devenparekh `empById` is undefined, please validate the API once, why its undefined, I think if you set `empById` to {} on initialization it will solve your issue!

Comment: nope it is still showing the same error on setting the empById value to {}. I am confused as this piece of code is working in stackblitz just fine but giving rendering errors in vscode